# Can I use environment variables to make Celery worker connect to a different worker?

Tags: docker, celery

I'm starting Celery worker in the way described by the manual...

```
$ stoneid salimfadhley$ celery worker

 -------------- celery@TCR-C02X29QPJHC9.local v4.2.1 (windowlicker)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Darwin-18.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit 2018-11-13 14:00:20
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x10fb4ee48 (.default.Loader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[2018-11-13 14:00:21,065: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

Can I provide some configuration (preferably via an environment variable) so that the worker connects to a different broker address?

According to the manual, I can use the **-b** flag to specify a broker URL via a command line, and I can wrap the worker in a script which pulls the environment variable and stuffs it into the command line argument of celery worker... but can I bypass this? Is there an environment variable I can set which the worker will pick up?

I'm actually running this inside a Docker container - the easiest way to provide this information would be as an environment variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The majority of the settings can be set via env vars. The naming convention is prefix with CELERY_ and then uppercase the setting name.

In this case the setting is `broker_url`, therefore the env var is `CELERY_BROKER_URL`.

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation where it states you can use env vars?

Comment: there is nothing in the docs (I think it was mentioned at some point in the past but I am not sure as it's been a while since I wrote this answer). It seems to be an open issue (https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4284) and having scanned through the source code it does look messy (e.g. https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/95015a1d5a60d94d8e1e02da4b9cf16416c747e2/celery/bin/celery.py#L139) so maybe it should be discouraged.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with Celery's out-of-the-box Django config compatibility (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html - even though it doesn't make a specific reference to environment variables). e.g. the CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY env var lets you set the worker's concurrency.

Comment: i guess there is not a documentation link for 'how to config everything via env var'. i also did a quick code search and found only some very small things can be set via env var for celery. (my work around is to write env var for each thing i need to config via env var.)

Comment: I do something like this in my projects 
```app.conf.update({'broker_url': os.environ['CELERY_BROKER_URL'], 'result_backend': os.environ['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'], 'result_expires': int(os.environ['CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES'])
})```

Comment: i do something similar but requires more lines. for each config setting i do `CELERY_NAME_A = ...` then later `app.conf.name_a = NAME_A`. The `...` is because i cast some values to `bool` or `int` or `float` and some have an assert check.

Comment: ```CELERY_BROKER_URL``` worked for 4.3.0